# How can I have an event listener that triggers on a cascading delete in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have some models in SQLAlchemy, and I need to execute an action (removing a file from disk) whenever the record associated to that file is deleted. However, binding a listener to the 'remove' event for that object doesn't do the trick.

Example :

```
class ModelA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'modela'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class ModelB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'modelb'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_modela = Column(Key, ForeignKey('modela.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True, nullable=True, default=None)
    modela = relationship('ModelA', backref=backref('modelbs', passive_deletes='all', lazy="dynamic"))

    id_foo = Column(Key, ForeignKey('modelc.id', ondelete="SET NULL"), index=True, nullable=True)
    foo = relationship('ModelC', foreign_keys='ModelB.id_foo', backref='modelbs')

class ModelC(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'modelc'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = Column(String(256), nullable=False)

@event.listens_for(ModelB.foo, 'remove', propagate=True)
def my_listener(modela, foo, initiator):
    os.remove(modela.foo.path)
```

The above listener is never called whenever a DELETE query is sent on the `modela` table. How can I make it so that sqlalchemy handles such cascading deletions and call my event listener whenever a delete is sent on a parent table ?